# how to secure site against unnecessary http request in php

Tags: php

One of my server is experiencing a dos attack with thousands of request per minute by some russian ip address.

To this effect, am trying to setup this code at the beginning of my script to block an ip which has made too much requests per seconds. I do not have money to go for sucuri or cloudfare etc.

1.) For example, i want check if the ip has made request **one second ago, 2 seconds ago, 3 seconds ago** etc. and then block them

2.) About performance which solution is the best. saving data to mysql or to a text file.

3.) will this block googlebots and other good bots crawling site for indexing.

The code below shows how i can insert users ip in a text file.

```
            $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            $file = fopen("ipcheck/file.txt","a");
            fwrite($file,$user_ip.PHP_EOL);
            fclose($file);
            echo " success";
```

The code below show how I can check if the user is in array and block them

```
$ips = file("ipcheck/file.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
if (in_array($user_ip, $ips)) {
echo "ip block";
}
```

please how do I pass the time in the check. I guess i have to do something like this but does not know how to integrate 
it properly

```
filemtime($user_ip) + 1 || $user_ip) + 2>= time();
touch(microtime(true));
```

**Updated section:**

This code is based on link submitted by Jelly Bean in his comment. It uses throtle method to avoid dos.

**My question** is that since its based on sessions. Its not possible  for those satanic dos bot to clear session/cookies on each request and thus bypass the session incrementation count. what will be the solution if its possible..

```
/**
ABUSE CHECK
Throttle client requests to avoid DoS attack
*/
session_start();
$usage = array(5,5,5,5,10,20,30,40,50,60,120,180,240); // seconds to wait after each request
if (isset($_SESSION['use_last'])) {
$nextin = $_SESSION['use_last']+$usage[$_SESSION['use_count']];
if (time() < $nextin) {
echo 'Please wait '.($nextin-time()).' seconds&hellip;';
die();
}else{
$_SESSION['use_count']++;
if ($_SESSION['use_count'] > sizeof($usage)-1) {$_SESSION['use_count']=sizeof($usage)-1;}
}
}else{
$_SESSION['use_count'] = 0;
}
$_SESSION['use_last'] = time();
// Execute code here
```

Comment: this may be of help [Throttle client request to avoid dos attack](https://gist.github.com/luckyshot/6077693)

Comment: @Jelly. there are up to three different php codes. Eg.  abusecheck.php, hrottlerequest.php, ip-based.php etc. do i have to use all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2.) About performance which solution is the best. saving data to mysql or to a text file

Saving to a file should be faster, of course. Main problem is that searching is slower without any data mapping/indexing.

> 3.) will this block googlebots and other good bots crawling site for indexing.

Of course, it may block bots which ignore your robots.txt instructions (if any).

If you really would like to create a very simple DOS defense - here's MySQL table structure sample for IPv4 logging:

```
CREATE TABLE `visitors`
(
    `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `ip` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    INDEX (`timestamp`),
    INDEX (`ip`)

) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Column `ip` is `INT UNSIGNED` here which is equal to uint32 C language type structure (non-negative integer with a size of 4 bytes). Don't store IP addresses as strings - they are numbers. And your processor compare numbers faster than strings.

To convert IPs from strings to numbers and back in PHP you may use ip2long and long2ip.

To convert IPs from strings to numbers and back in MySQL/MariaDB you can use INET_ATON and INET_NTOA functions.

```
-- INSERT sample (logs visitor):
INSERT INTO `visitors` (`ip`) VALUES (INET_ATON('23.34.45.56'))

-- SELECT sample (shows all visits from a specific IP):
SELECT * FROM `visitors` WHERE ip = INET_NTOA('23.34.45.56')

-- COUNT sample (counts visits from the specific IP during the last 1 hour):
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `visitors` WHERE `ip` = INET_ATON('23.34.45.56') AND `timestamp` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)

-- TRUNCATE sample (erases old data from the table, run it as a cron task once a day):
DELETE FROM `visitors` WHERE `timestamp` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Extra hints:

1. Some visitors can use same IP addresses, so remember it when you
   specify any limit value.
2. You may place your IP logger/verification code before CMS or framework autoloader to prevent unnecessary resource draining.
3. Send 503 or 429 HTTP code to bots which DOS your
   website, so they'll know that they should come later.
4. Don't forget about robots.txt, most of bots read this file and follow your rules (e.g. `crawl-delay` directive).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I want to combine your solution with jelly Bean solutions provided in comment the link above. I have a final question. If Increment bot access count via session. Is not possible for bot to clear session on each request and  thus bypass the code. I will update my my post with  that. please see  updated section.

Comment: @jmarkatti, I am afraid that most bots (especially which cause DOS attacks) don't use sessions at all. They should store session ID somewhere between connections and I don't believe that they do it for any reason.

Comment: please Can you see the updated section of my post and see if there is any loop hole on it before I combine it with yours. Thanks

Comment: @jmarkatti, my comment above explains everything. Session-based solution may work against real visitors only or against scrappers which emulate authorization to receive an access to data which is behind the auth form.

Comment: @jmarkatti, my suggestion is to deal with IP addresses only. Log visitors, check how many pages they opened during the last N minutes and block them when they reach the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running an **Apache Server** with PHP and a mysql database, **the most comprehensive and responsive solution would be to not program the DOS protection yourself**.

There are several ways you can block these connections, either through manual IP blacklisting in .htaccess ([blacklisting specific IPs](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-ip-address/)), or through timeouts and extensions built on the Apache server itself. [Here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/misc/security_tips.html) is more information on a variety of solutions.

If this does not solve you problem there are a bunch of other ways to block incoming connections without filling up your database with unnecessary crap.

Comment: am on share hosting and am not sure they allow installation of mod_evasive or  mod_security. I already know how to black list in the .htaccess but the ip is changing

Answer (score 0):

Some of the examples in @JellyBean's comment-link would do what you're asking, but I agree with @shn that rate-limiting of HTTP requests probably doesn't belong in your PHP application.

(As an aside, rate-limiting of sign-in attempts, or other in-app behavior, probably *does* belong in your app, or in any external user-management system you use.)

The Apache-specific suggestions [shn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56549976/10135377) links to are fine practice for *mitigating* DOS attacks, but they're not exactly rate-limiting. NGinX has [a module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) that actually does per-ip rate-limiting. I imaging Apache has one somewhere, but I don't know Apache as well.

If you're using load-balancing or any other kind of reverse proxy, it's a good idea to have rate-limiting as high up in that stack as practical. For example, in AWS one might use [WAF Rate-based rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/how-aws-waf-works.html).

If you don't have control over your hosting environment, than to an extent this kind of defense shouldn't be your problem. Talk to your service-provider and see what they suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the tips